# change a range of items in a dictionary in order O(n)

Tags: python

I am trying to change a range of values in a dictionary in runtime of `O(n)`.
Where n is number of elements in the range that I need to change.

for example if my dictionary has numbers for keys, and I am getting a list of range of keys
list = [ (key1,key3), (key2,key3)]
in this case if I start with
`d = {key1: odd , key2: even, key3: odd , key4: even}`
So I will have 
after the first range
`d = {key1: even , key2: odd, key3: even , key4: even}`
after the second range of keys
`d = {key1: even , key2: even, key3: odd , key4: even}`

can it be achieved in python?

Comment: What's `n`? The number of elements in the dictionary? The length of the range? The number of elements which will need to change?

Comment: The ordering of the keys is arbitrary, so it's not really clear how you can choose the keys to change using a numeric range. Do you have another variable storing the order of the keys?

Comment: dicts are unordered, so you can't index them.

Comment: My keys are numbers from 0-infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you really mean by n is the length of the range list, there is no way to achieve this using a dictionary. For example, if the range is [(0,100000000000)], doing this in a dictionary would take exponentially long with respect to the number of bits in the range list.

You can achieve your operations in nlogn, where n is length of the range list, if you chose the correct data representation and algorithm. This is in general exponentially faster than a runtime of O(n) with respect to the actual number of elements in the range.

Here is a possible solution:

1. Define a data structure consisting of range lists. The elements that fall inside a range in the list have been 'flipped' from their original, starting state.
2. Define a routine that 'merges' a new set of flips (an incoming range list) with the existing one, and finds the disjoint set of flips.

The routine should:

1. Merge the data structure's ranges with the incoming range list.
2. Find set of ranges with smallest first element, call it A.
3. Find set of ranges which start before the last range in A ends, merge it with A.
4. Sort the ranges in A according to first element.
5. Split each range (a,b) in A into (a,b1) and (b1,b), for each (b1,?) in A. The ranges in A should now be non-overlapping.
6. Delete all pairs of (a,b). (a,b) should now be unique in A.
7. Concatenate all the ranges (a,b), (b,c) into (a,c) in A.
8. Add A to the data structure. Go to step 2, starting with next smallest element not yet added.

Comment: I am still thinking of the solution that you suggested. Once I have a better understanding I will either let you know or accept the answer :)

Comment: It was a school project. As you can see in my initial inquiry I did not ask for a solution, just wanted to know if python can perform a certain action in O(n).

Comment: Well, the answer is Yes, if "n is number of elements in the range that I need to change". But I doubt that this is what your project means, because that would be pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.  This is O(n) where n is the number of keys you need to *change*.

```
change_keys = (1,2)
for key in change_keys:
    d[key] = 'odd' if d[key]=='even' else 'even'
```

---

If you have a list of range tupless, e.g.:

```
key_ranges = [(2,6), (4,8)]
key_ranges = [ range(a[0],a[1]) for a in key_ranges ]
```

I believe you could just use:

```
change_keys = set.union(*map(set,key_ranges))
```

But then, of course, it takes operations to generate the set.  But at some point you either have to duplicate the keys, or find the duplicates.  Not sure it can be avoided.

Or if you want to do the duplicates, just never call `set`:

```
key_ranges = [(2,6), (4,8)]
change_keys = []
for a in key_ranges:
    change_keys.extend(range(a[0],a[1])
```

Comment: This won't achieve order n if you have several change keys in a list. For example 
`change_keys = [(key2,key3) , (key5,key6)]`

Comment: This will only change the value at key 1 and key 2, not the range from 1 to 2. If the last number was 3 it would skip 2.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand either above comment.  Quantico, because of the nested list? @TylerFerraro, this seems to match the question, `(1,2)` is a tuple, not `range(1,2)`.

Comment: @Quantico: why do you think this wouldn't be O(n)? You're doing basically one operation per key.

Comment: Because if you get a list of tuples (that represent the range) (start, end). if you want to update your dictionary you will have to do a nested for loop. `for element in list of tuples` , for `key in change_keys`

Comment: Oh, so you do mean `range(start,end)`?

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that you're doing one operation per key, and (hopefully) not repeating any keys in your ranges, it'll be O(n). The total number of operations, even with the nested for loop, is something like `sum(len(eachrange) for eachrange in list_of_tuples)`.

Comment: but you might have overlaps in your keys.

Comment: could you explain how the set will cover the case when you have to switch twice from odd to even. for example (1,2) , (2,3). you will have to change 1 and 3 once, and 2 twice. a union will result in (1,2,3)

Comment: Wait, you _want_ the overlaps?  I was trying to avoid them :-P

Comment: @Quantico: it's very hard for people to give you the answer you want when you don't seem to know what that is. Your most recent comment seems to completely contradict your earlier requests to have an O(n) algorithm even when there's overlapping ranges.

Comment: @ askewchan, yes I do. As you can see from my example I am taking the overlaps into consideration.

Comment: @Marius I am sorry if my example was not clear, I did not ment to confuse anyone

Comment: No worries, @Quantico, I think I've fixed it.  Your first example only had one range in the question, and I only read your comments here after that.  I hope this helps anyway!

Comment: You need to define an algorithm for finding a disjoint range list from your input.

Comment: @ealfonso is right, and if you expect to have lots of overlapping ranges, you might actually save computation (?) by counting each key in your `change_keys` list and discarding any that show up an even number of times.  However, you're still not saving the number of keys.

Comment: Here is a hint for OP: start by sorting the range list by the first element. 

@askewchan Counting each key in change_keys takes exponentially long if n is the number of ranges in the list. 

OP:
You probably should think about the design of your data structure. If you need to flip the range (0,10000000), that will take exponentially long with respect to the number of bits in the input if you are using a dict.

Comment: @ealfonso, that is why I was thinking on a dict insert,set and lookup time are constant.

Comment: Check out my answer: there is no way to achieve an O(n) if n is the length of the range list. You need to use a more efficient data representation.

Comment: Quantico:

Is infinity ever included as one of your range endpoints?

Are you sure that by n you don't mean the length of the range list?